# Pyspark integration into Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, pyspark, elasticsearch

I'm a bit lost on how to confiure Pycharm so I can directly run scripts within Pyspark. I'm using Pyspark ontop of an Elasticsearch cluster and using the following code to run the script. It's running with the default python interpreter as I tried to configure the pyspark shell as interpreter, but that didn't work with the error it's not a valid SDK:

```
__author__ = 'lucas'


from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

if __name__ == "__main__":

    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ESTest")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    es_read_conf = {
        "es.nodes" : "localhost",
        "es.port" : "9200",
        "es.resource" : "titanic/passenger"
    }
    es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
        keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
        valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
        conf=es_read_conf)

    es_write_conf = {
        "es.nodes" : "localhost",
        "es.port" : "9200",
        "es.resource" : "titanic/value_counts"
    }

    doc = es_rdd.first()[1]

    for field in doc:

        value_counts = es_rdd.map(lambda item: item[1][field])
        value_counts = value_counts.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
        value_counts = value_counts.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
        value_counts = value_counts.filter(lambda item: item[1] > 1)
        value_counts = value_counts.map(lambda item: ('key', {
            'field': field,
            'val': item[0],
            'count': item[1]
        }))

        value_counts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
            path='-',
            outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
            keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
            valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
            conf=es_write_conf)
```

But this generates the following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lucas/PycharmProjects/tweetspark/analytics/tweetanalyzer.py", line 20, in <module>
    conf=es_read_conf)
  File "/var/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 601, in newAPIHadoopRDD
    jconf, batchSize)
  File "/var/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/var/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDDFromClassNames(PythonRDD.scala:519)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: you can try https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707

Answer (score 3):

What you are missing is the elasticsearch-spark.jar.
Download [ElasticSearch-Hadoop integration](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/hadoop), find the elasticsearch-spark under the `dist` subdirectory, then set SPARK_CLASSPATH environment variable

```
os.environ['SPARK_CLASSPATH'] = "/path/to/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.3.0/dist/elasticsearch-spark_2.10-2.3.0.jar"
```

Answer (score 2):

The stacktrace is complaining about a missing jar. You might be able to add it to the classpath by adding this code before you start the `SparkContext`:

```
import os
os.environ['SPARK_CLASSPATH'] = "/path/to/elasticsearch-hadoop.jar"

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ESTest")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

...
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using `pipenv` and `pyspark` for local development in `pycharm`. In order to not introduce any code specifing the path of external jars into your project, you could download the jars missing and copy them to the default jar file path.

## how to find the default path including jar files needed by pyspark.

1. find the path in virtual python environment

```
$ which pyspark
/Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/demo-spark-ZXzB9uOI/bin/pyspark
```

2. run `find_spark_home.py` under `/Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/demo-spark-ZXzB9uOI/bin/` and get the path of spark home

```
$ python /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/demo-spark-ZXzB9uOI/bin/find_spark_home.py

/Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/abnormal_detection-ZXzB9uOI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark
```

then the default path is `/Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/abnormal_detection-ZXzB9uOI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars`

3. copy external jar files to the default path

```
$ cp xxxx.jar /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/abnormal_detection-ZXzB9uOI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/
```

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is:

```
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = \
    '--jars /full/path/to/your/jar.jar pyspark-shell'
# example
# os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = \
# '--jars /home/buxizhizhoum/jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-6.4.2/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.4.2.jar ' \
# 'pyspark-shell'
```

works on spark 2.3 and elasticsearch 6.4
the jars needed could be founded from https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-hadoop/elasticsearch-hadoop-6.4.2.zip

Comment: It works for me. with pyspark 2.4.3 es 6.6.0 and jar file elasticsearch-hadoop-6.6.0.jar.